# Помогите сделать проверку на введенную в lineEdit и lineEdit_2 строку, после чего при нажатии на pushButton открывалась бы некая ссылка

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

Все работает, но хочу понять, как объединить две проверки `lineEdit` и `lineEdit_2` на заданный текст и, чтобы при соответствии (в двух строках), выполнялась функция.

А если где-то текст не соответствует, то просто удалялся введенный текст из обоих строк.

**UPD**. Еще бы хотелось получить ответ на вопрос, как запретить изменение размера окна (чтобы было строго `Form.resize(400, 305))` после запуска программы?

Отрывок моего кода:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.bp)

....

    def bp(self):
        if self.lineEdit.text() == "admin":

        self.lineEdit_2.text() == "password":
            webbrowser.open('youtube.com', new=2)
```

Comment: if self.lineEdit.text() == "admin" and self.lineEdit_2.text() == "password": webbrowser.open('youtube.com', new=2) ?

Comment: Как текст у вас удалется, я, конечно, не знаю, поэтому с этим не помогу

Comment: "and" сработало. так как новичок, где-то пропустил видимо, что можно использовать это (признаюсь честно, что думал попробовать так, но почему-то отверг мысль, подумав, что было бы слишком просто). про удаление текста имею ввиду это: в lineEdit'ы ввел текст, но если он не соответствует тому, что я задал для выполнения функции, он бы удалялся из lineEdit'ов и пришлось бы каждый вводить заново.

Comment: Это вы уже сами сможете решить или ещё помощь нужна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import webbrowser
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # как запретить изменение размера окна после запуска программы?
        self.setFixedSize(400, 305)

        self.lineEdit   = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Открыть youtube.com")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.bp)

        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(QtWidgets.QLabel('Введите Login'), self.lineEdit)
        layout.addRow(QtWidgets.QLabel('Введите Password'), self.lineEdit_2)
        layout.addRow('', self.pushButton)


    def bp(self):
        if self.lineEdit.text() == "admin" and self.lineEdit_2.text() == "password":
            webbrowser.open('youtube.com', new=2)    
        else:
            self.lineEdit.clear()
            self.lineEdit_2.clear()
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 
                'Неправильный логин или пароль. Попробуйте еще раз. ')
            self.lineEdit.setFocus()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Widget()
#    window.resize(400, 305)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да сам интерфейс есть :) очистка после неудачных значений в строках работает. с изменением размера пытаюсь разобраться, куда впихнуть его в свой код. если что не получится - отпишу. UPD. все получилось. еще раз спасибо :)

Comment: @AtommX Если вы хотите получать правильные и быстрые ответы, и другие рекомендации - вы должны публиковать пример, который можно воспроизвести.

Comment: хорошо, учел. в следующий раз так и сделаю.